# Terminal doesn't return after process kill

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I run a Spring Boot app with the following command,

```
java -jar myapp-1.0.0.jar & echo $! > "myapp.pid"
```

and killing the process with the following command

```
kill `cat "myapp.pid"` or kill -9 `cat "myapp.pid"`
```

and when I checked process is killed but terminal doesn't return, it becomes hanged. When I press enter key, it returns normal. What is the problem here ?

Comment: What key do you press? I suspect you have a prompt, you just aren’t seeing it.

Comment: Any key, it is a spring boot app.

Comment: Not shift, alt, or control, but something like Enter or B...?

Comment: It looks only enter